# Hive UDF - exetremely slow when parsing IP addresses

Tags: java, performance, hive, user-defined-functions, hive-udf

I have a column which comprises ip addresses. Now I need to parse them to contries/cities:
`select IPUtils('199.999.999.999')` and it returns `['Aisa', 'Hongkong', 'xxx', 'Hongkong']`

I write a hive udf to do this but it runs exetremely slow, as shown below:

`INFO  : 2021-09-08 18:51:10,817 Stage-2 map = 100%,  reduce = 30%, Cumulative CPU 9074.06 sec`

`map = 100%` while progress of `reduce` **gains 1 percent every 15 minutes**.

The UDF reads file from the project's resource folder, so mayby it repeatly read the file again and again? The udf is shown as below, any help is appreciated:

```
public class IPUtil extends UDF {

    public List<String>  evaluate(String  ip){
        try{
            ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

            // I put the mmdb file in resource folder of the java project
            InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
            DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(is).build();

            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            CityResponse response = reader.city(ipAddress);
            Country country = response.getCountry();
            Subdivision subdivision = response.getMostSpecificSubdivision();
            City city = response.getCity();
            Continent continent = response.getContinent();

            List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

            list.add(continent.getNames().get("zh-CN"));
            list.add(country.getNames().get("zh-CN"));
            list.add(subdivision.getNames().get("zh-CN"));
            list.add(city.getNames().get("zh-CN"));

            return list;

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (GeoIp2Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test()throws Exception{
        System.out.println(evaluate("175.45.20.138"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This `            InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
            DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(is).build();` can be moved to the constructor... but it will not give you much improvement.

Comment: hi @leftjoin Your answer inspired me!!! I tried to put that part in a static block to ensure the `mmdb` file only gets loaded once when the class is initialled. Now the whole task finishes within 7 minutes!

Comment: I added the answer, you can accept/upvote if it was really useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this

```
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(is).build();
```

to the class initialization.

Comment: Also can consider make static class variable.